# How to run two different FFmpeg commands parallelly?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have one Intent service to work in background to execute compressing video file command because I want to compress video file upto 30GB (4KVideo), but meanwhile I want to run video merge, trim, rotate, add music commands as well, so how can I?

Because it giving me below error:

> FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException: FFmpeg command is already running, you are only allowed to run single command at a time

Please provide me any alternative solution for that

Comment: @HB, any other solution?

Comment: Here is a great explanation how you can achieve this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56336565/5550161